# Haskell function which acts differently depending on the monad type

Tags: haskell, monads, alternative-functor, monadplus

I'm trying to implement a function which usually puts the first element of a list in a monad, but if the monad is a list it returns the whole list:

```
putInMonad :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
putInMonad (s:sx) = return s
putInMonad _ = mzero
```

```
putInMonad [1,2,3] :: Maybe Int
```

Should return `Just 1`, and

```
putInMonad [1,2,3] :: [] Int
```

should return `[1,2,3]`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `[[]] Int` as lower monad.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No, because the expression `return s` doesn't contain any information about `sx`; simply providing a concrete return type doesn't help that.

Comment: @chepner: yeah I know it will not behave differently for that specific monad. I only had the idea to solve the problem the other way around: give it a list of lists instead of a list of items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your particular use-case, you could take advantage of `msum`:

```
putInMonad :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a
putInMonad x = msum $ map return x
```

Then both examples will work:

```
% putInMonad [1,2,3,4] :: Maybe Int
Just 1
% putInMonad [1,2,3,4] :: [Int]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Note however that `Maybe` is not exactly `MonadPlus`, since `mplus` there is not associative.

Comment: Any unease/controversy about `MonadPlus` might be avoided by switching to `Alternative` and `asum`, if the `MonadPlus` constraint isn't a hard requirement for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't do this, because the function cannot know which `Foo` instance will be used when the function is called, meaning it has no basis for deciding to return `return s` or `return (s:sx)`.

In this particular case, there is a workaround (see [@marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42005779/1126841)) when `Foo` is `MonadPlus`.

Comment: Waiting for votes to tell me if I'm technically right, or just flat out wrong.

Comment: You are not technically right, but merely because the class in question is `MonadPlus`, which offers the workaround shown in marc's answer. That this is impossible in the general case is still a point worth making. I suggest editing your answer to make this subtlety clear and/or point towards marc's answer for the sake of contrast.